# eclipse will not find ADB.exe or SDK

Tags: android, sdk

I am going nuts.I update to the Android SDK in Eclipse, Eclipse can't find the SDK. There is a text not that saids the the file has been moved to /platform-tools, however the file ADB.exe is nowhere to be found in any of my folders. The SDK Manager works find but for some reason Eclipse will not find the file its looking for. I have looked everywhere for the answer. It work find for about 4 months until I upgraded. I also now using a real device a Droid X2. But I don't believe this is the issue. I can't find the ADB.exe file. Help been working on this for about 2 days

Comment: Don't you have to install the platform tools separately?

Answer (score 5):

`adb.exe` was relocated from {ANDROID_SDK_FOLDER}/tools to {ANDROID_SDK_FOLDER}/platform-tools: find your SDK folder and look inside it for the `platform-tools` folder.

EDIT: in Eclipse, if you open the Preferences dialog (Window->Preferences) and select the Android option on the left it will show you what Eclipse THINKS is your Android SDK folder. If you moved the SDK folder you should update the path to match the new location of the SDK folder, and then (a restart might be necessary) Eclipse should work fine with the Android tools.

EDIT: well, I can't tell if your ADT isn't properly installed or if the SDK location is broken, so lets try and brute force set the SDK location. Create a text file on your desktop called "adt.pref", and then place only this line in it:

```
/instance/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.sdk=C\:\\Program Files\\Android\\android-sdk
```

then in Eclipse select *File*->*Import* then select **General**->**Preferences** and then pick that file. This should force the ADT location to match what that is. Restart Eclipse and see if that improves things.

Comment: I have and it is not there. I have deleted it and re-installed the SDK serveral times. But again before the upgrade it worked for serveral months. The file is nowhere, was it renamed and Eclipse can't get to it. Is it possible that a zip file may have to file and I can copy it to the folder? Thanks

Comment: Ah, do you mean there is a location in the preferences dialog and there is nothing at that location? I don't think there is a zip file you can copy: you either have to install it from scratch or find where on disk it was re-installed to and enter it into that field in the Preferences dialog. You can change the location: you just need to find the SDK on your hard drive, and there really can't be too many places you might have installed it to.

Comment: Hi again, Yes the ADT work well from the sdk, SDK Manager. However the ADT Plug-in cannot be found. I get"could not find SDK folder" When loading Eclipse. Also when I try starting th ADT Manger I get "Location of Android SDK had not been setuo in the preferences" However can't find the file need, everything else is there but the file ADB.exe

Comment: What folder is SDK Manager in?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk

Comment: Thanks Femi, Although your solution did not completely work. You put me on the right trail. The perferences should be c:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk not the platform-tools folder or tools folder. Thanks very very much for your help. It is people like you that makes this site work. Thanks again... Thanks also ScottB

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it by running the android sdk-manager (you can do that without running eclipse, using the start menu shortcut) and installing the Android SDK Platform-Tools through it (select the square and click install packages...).

Answer (score 1):

Download the SDK [here.](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Once that's done, I would just follow the Google installation instructions again from the beginning. Perhaps you're missing something fairly simple?

[Installation instructions.](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html)

Comment: Reinstalled the SDK serveral times.

Comment: I'm not talking just about the SDK. Did you update the ADT plugin in eclipse? 

How about adding the SDK folder in Eclipse?

Comment: Hi again, Yes the ADT work well from the sdk, SDK Manager. However the ADT Plug-in cannot be found. I get

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. In my case it was caused by an upgrade on the Java JDK. I was using 1.6 and upgraded to 1.7.

Just manually add the new JDK to Eclipse.

Right click on your project JRE System Library. Select installed JRE, and then find it on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and when I looked inside the platform-tools folder, it was empty.
After searching for downloading the contect of this folder, I found the below link.

http://venomvendor.blogspot.com/2012/06/android-adt-20-updated-download-offline.html

But it also could not help me.
At last I found that it's related to my internet connection.